# PdfDocument Print on Two page

Tags: android, bitmap, pdf-generation

Hey I've converted my custom listview in Bitmap. Size of my bitmap is large So I want to print that bitmap in two separate pages of pdf file using PdfDocument class. I've searched for the same but don't get proper solution. Can any one help me!!??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting the bitmap into two parts before using the PdfDoucment class.

```
Bitmap source;            //original bitmap file
Bitmap page1=Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight()/2);
Bitmap page2=Bitmap.createBitmap(source,0,source.getHeight()/2,source.getWidth(),source.getHeight());
```